# Parsing error when attempting to import unique ASCII file into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have attached my data file, when I try and import it into a pandas dataframe, I get the following error:

```
ParserError: Expected 6 fields in line 342, saw 12. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.
```

Here is my code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('/content/drive/My Drive/MAT 395/RaivathariSinghania/ALDalumina.gr', header=None, delim_whitespace=True, engine="python", skiprows=136)
```

Any help on getting around this error would be very helpful, I've been looking all over the internet and haven't found a solution as of yet.

File is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_nV3fNvuV8xfJR-Gmv159cKGuKcQ6NOp/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Pandas doesn't support `gr` extension files as per my knowledge.

`gr` files are primarily associated with XGMML (eXtensible Graph Markup and Modeling Language) File.

I don't think you can directly load `gr` files directly to pandas.

Probably this link https://gist.github.com/informationsea/4284956 will help you.

Comment: My prof said you can use pandas to import them, because its just an ASCII file in the end. Also he said we could use stack overflow for help, but wants us to figure it out.

Comment: Probably you can read the file using `lxml` and parse it as in this tutorial - https://medium.com/@robertopreste/from-xml-to-pandas-dataframes-9292980b1c1c

Comment: Thanks will have a look!